# Passing jQuery this.id in class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have two different input fields, it uses typeahead.

In first field we enter Country and in other we should select City, depending on Country.
So I'm making a javascript/jQuery function, to pass field ID, to know, which of 3 pairs of Country+City pair am I selecting.

i'm using

```
 $('.demoTypeAhead').typeahead({
     source: getCityForCountry($(this).id)
 });
```

in function getCityForCountry, I would like to pass a field specific id, but neither $(this), or this works, since it returns whole DOM object.

Comment: can you please make an jsfiddle for it, would gladly help.

Answer (score 6):

A jQuery object does not have an `.id` property. You either want

```
this.id // or
$(this).prop("id") // or even
$(this).attr("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

$(this) on this scope does not return input as an object, but whole page as an object...

Just made jsfiddle for it:
    `Jsfiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/s1d8nmqr/3/
I would like to reload data source of typeahead for second input, when I select first one (2 level select)